# JAVA JSON Restfull WebService No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: java, json, rest, cors, jax-ws

I have a JAVA RESTful webservice which will return JSON string and it was written in Java. My problem is when I send request to that webservice with below URL

```
http://localhost:8080/WebServiceXYZ/Users/insert
```

it's giving me the below error message

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/WebServiceXYZ/Users/insert/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Here is my Code

```
package com.lb.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/Users")
public class RegistrationService
{
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/insert")
    public String InsertCredentials (String json) throws JSONException
    {
        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

        String phone = null;
        JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject result1 = obj.getJSONObject("Credentials");
            phone = result1.getString("phone");
            DBConnection conn = new DBConnection();

            int checkUserID = conn.GetUserIDByPhone(phone);
            if(checkUserID <= 0)
            {
                DBConnection.InsertorUpdateUsers(phone, currentTime);
            }

            int userID = conn.GetUserIDByPhone(phone);
            int otp = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*1000);

            DBConnection.InsertorUpdateCredentials(userID, otp, currentTime);

            JSONObject createObj = new JSONObject();
            createObj.put("phone", phone);
            createObj.put("otp", otp);
            createObj.put("reqDateTime", currentTime);
            returnJson.put("Credentials", createObj);

            System.out.println(returnJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return returnJson.toString();
    }
}
```

My web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WebServiceXYZ</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.lb.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I already read many articles but no progress, so please let me know, How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is assuming you are using jetty as your server. hope it helps...

add the following code to your web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
  <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
  <param-value>origin, content-type, accept</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.M0</version>
</dependency>
```

the link to configure tomcat is [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter_and_HttpServletRequest_attributes)... here is another [link2](http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html) modify accordingly :)

Comment: in my project there is no "pom.xml" file.

Comment: are you using a maven project?? if not then you wont be having a pom.xml file. in that scenario it would be better to download the jar file and add it manually to your path. this is assuming you are using jetty as your server

Comment: I am not using a maven project.

Comment: I am not using a maven project, sorry for typo..

Comment: are you using jetty as your server?

Comment: when i add org.eclipse.jetty jetty-servlets jar to my lib folder and add filter, my tomcat8 not started.

Comment: I am using Tomcat8 server.

Comment: i updated my answer go through the link it has the configuration for tomcat... change it accordingly and mark this as the right answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Should i delete all filter and org.eclipse.jetty jetty-servlets jar from lib folder?

Comment: yes remove jetty jar

Comment: @user3441151 i have edited my answer with couple of more links. be sure to check them out. hope your issue is resolved.

Comment: with the help of http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html link "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error solved, but after this i got new error "415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

Comment: Unsupported media type is because you are calling you service using some other http method. in your code above it is a POST method. Therefore make the call to your rest service using POST request and if it has solved your problem then dont forget to mark this answer as the correct answer

Comment: should i change post to get?

Comment: if you change it from POST to GET then you will not be able to send the json in your request. use POST to send in your request.

Comment: what should i change in my code to resolved error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110459/discussion-between-abhishek-and-user3441151).

Comment: can you join chat again?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the header for the HttpServletResponse

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Path("/Users")
public class RegistrationService
{

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    private void allowCrossDomainAccess() {
        if (servletResponse != null){
            servletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/insert")
    public String InsertCredentials (String json) throws JSONException
    {
        allowCrossDomainAccess();
        // your code here
    }
}
```